# Activity has leaked window that was originally added with progress dialog

Tags: android

I have this code here:  I have this code here:  I have this code here:

```
public class MainTask extends Activity {

private boolean flag=false;
private Context context;
private String url;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private View view;

public MainTask(Context context,String url,View view) {
    this.url=url;
    this.view=view;
    this.context=context;
    BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask();
    task.execute();
}


private Void MainThread() {
    int  leave=0;
    int  pass=0;
    
    while(true){
                                                
        if(leave==-1){
            flag=true;
            break;
        }
        else if(pass==Preferences.vcheckimage.size())
            break;
        
        for(int i=0;i<Preferences.vcheckimage.size();i++){
            
            if(Preferences.vcheckimage.get(i).equals("-1")){
                leave=-1;
                break;
            }
            else{
                pass++;
            }
        }
    return null;  
}


private class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    
    public BitmapDownloaderTask() {
        
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.setEnabled(false);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setTitle("Processing...");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
        pd.setCancelable(false);                  
        pd.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return MainThread();
    }
     
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         
        pd.dismiss();
        
        if(flag){           
         Toast.makeText(context,"Image is not available yet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
     
    }
}
 }
```

but when i run this i get the following error:

```
 05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850): Activity com.mypkg.myP has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44c46ff0 that was originally added here
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity ccom.mypkg.myP has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44c46ff0 that was originally added here
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:231)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at com.mypkg.myP$PreparePairingLinkageData.onPreExecute(viewP.java:183)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at com.mypkg.myP.onCreate(viewP.java:94)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:126)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Has anyone idea why is this happen? I saw and other posts but didn't help me.

Comment: What does `MainThread` do and does it ever end before the application? If not then that's probably your problem. I would guess that `pd.dismiss()` never gets called

Comment: @codeMagic valid point. Tony pls post what your `MainThread` code

Comment: The comments are saying code.Which means i've wriiten something there that end the while loop.

Comment: @Tony also why `dialog.dismiss()` in `onPreExecute`

Comment: When button is pressed dialog is closed

Comment: put -  if(pd != null) { pd.dismiss(); }  - in your onPause() method.

Comment: Not working.onPause() method doesn't even execute

Comment: Is the `Activity` exiting somewhere before the task finishes?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `BitmapDownloaderTask`
being internal to `MainThread`
is the whole problem. Try matching the brackets the issue should be resolved.

**EDIT:**
Last bit from my side. My MainThread code would be this

```
private Void MainThread() {
        int leave = 0;
        int pass = 0;

        while(true) {

            if(leave==-1) {
                flag=true;
                break;
            } 
            else if(pass==Preferences.vcheckimage.size())
                break;

            for(int i=0;i<Preferences.vcheckimage.size();i++) {
                if(Preferences.vcheckimage.get(i).equals("-1")) {
                    leave=-1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    pass++;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        return null;  
    }
```

Comment: Its not internal.Runs great without the dialog progress

Comment: at least the code you have pasted above has some issue related to that. I took your code as it is and in 
`public MainTask(Context context,String url,View view) {
    this.url=url;
    this.view=view;
    this.context=context;
    BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask();
    task.execute();
}` I am getting _BitmapDownloaderTask cannot be resolved to a type_